# Thread block after 1st call

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads

I have two threads ODD and EVEN which are supposed to print Odd and Even numbers consecutively.
I have used a Binary Semaphore "mutex" initialized with value 1.
Irrespective of which one runs first, it only prints once "Even - 0".

The "ODD" thread never starts even though cnt = 1 and the mutex is also released.

If I use another Semaphore with Initial value 0 and use it at the End of "EVEN" thread to signal "ODD" thread then it works fine.

But my question is when "EVEN" function releases "mutex" and increase "cnt", shouldn't the ODD function also proceed?

```
  
// C program to demonstrate working of Semaphores
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
  
sem_t mutex,OE;
int i=0, n=50;
  
void* odd(void* arg)
{
    while(n--) {
    //sem_wait(&OE);
        while(i % 2 == 0)
            sem_wait(&mutex);
        printf("Odd : %d \n",i);
        i += 1;
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }
}
  
void* even(void* arg)
{
    while(n--) {
        while(i % 2 != 0)
            sem_wait(&mutex);
        printf("Even : %d \n",i);
        i += 1; 
        sem_post(&mutex);
    //sem_post(&OE);
    }
}
    
  
int main()
{
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    //sem_init(&OE, 0, 0);
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,odd,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,even,NULL);
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's possible the wrong thread wakes. E.g. even thread wakes twice, number is not odd so it waits again

Comment: If you must do this with semaphores, then use two: each thread waits for one and posts to the other.  Even with the extra semaphore, it's still simpler, not to mention more efficient and more reliable.

Comment: Agree @SupportUkraine . I have added the entire code

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that one thread may take the semaphore and hold on to it so that the other thread can't get it.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
  
sem_t mutex;
int i=0, ng=25;
  
void* odd(void* arg)
{
    (void)arg;
    int n = ng;
    while(n--) {
        while(1) {
            sem_wait(&mutex); 
            if (i % 2 != 0) break; 
            sem_post(&mutex);      // Notice
        }
        printf("Odd : %d \n",i);
        i += 1;
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
  
void* even(void* arg)
{
    (void)arg;
    int n = ng;
    while(n--) {
        while(1) {
            sem_wait(&mutex); 
            if (i % 2 == 0) break; 
            sem_post(&mutex);      // Notice
        }
        printf("Even : %d \n",i);
        i += 1; 
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
    
  
int main()
{
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,odd,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,even,NULL);
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: To keep things short, this code doesn't check function return values. In real code that must be added.

Comment: This solution leads to Deadlock.  Using the same semaphore for both threads can be buggy. When you try to run this code for NG=2500, do you see all the prints getting generated?
The solution which I provided works fine when I uncomment the lines using "OE" semaphore. I don't want a solution, I wanted to understand OE is required.
I got it why it would not work without OE, will paste the solution in my orginal thread

Comment: @HarshAgarwal " When you try to run this code for NG=2500 , do you see all the prints getting generated?" yes, no problems and no deadlocks.

Comment: Not sure, it's not working in the online compiler. Can you please try the below one
https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/